# MS SQL Query for Opening Stock calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate opening stock as shown in linked picture, i have millions of records and 100+ location. can any one guide me. I have used mentioned blow query but this query is too show on millions of records.

create table #temp
(
item nvarchar(20),
Location nvarchar(10),
[Transaction Date] date,
price decimal(20,2),
Qty int,
price_Change decimal(20,2))

insert  #temp  SELECT   'Itm-005' , 'A' , '2017-01-05' , '10' , '13' , '0' 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'Itm-007' , 'A' , '2017-01-15' , '15' , '20' , '0'
 UNION ALL SELECT 'Itm-007' , 'B' , '2017-01-16' , '14' , '14' , '0' 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'Itm-007' , 'A' , '2017-01-21' , '17' , '6' , '2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Itm-005' , 'A' , '2017-01-25' , '8' , '17' , '-2' 
 UNION ALL SELECT 'Itm-007' , 'A' , '2017-01-27' , '13' , '6' , '-4'

select * from #temp

select Item, Location,[Transaction Date],Price,Qty, Price_change 
 , (select isnull(sum(qty),0) from #temp c where c.item=p.item and c.Location=p.Location and c.[Transaction Date] < p.[Transaction Date]) [Opening Stock]
 from #temp p

[image: Need Opening Stock]

Comment: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: post your query in the question not as image

Comment: You can try this on your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709587/how-to-calculate-opening-and-closing-quantity-balances-sql-server
Then ask if its not working.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt. And specify sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as an image (or link to an image.)

Comment: Jarlh : i have shared my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,

i have worked out with my same query, although seed was slow. query is mentioned below:-

select Item, Location,[Transaction Date],Price,Qty, Price_change , (select isnull(sum(qty),0) from #temp c where c.item=p.item and c.Location=p.Location and c.[Transaction Date] < p.[Transaction Date]) [Opening Stock] from #temp p